# How to focus on textfield that is outside of view in tableview?

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, uitextfield

So I have the below code set inside cellForRowAt and it works perfect except when I have lets say 10+ cells already and the user presses the + button to add a new cell it doesn't focus on that textField because it's outside of the view. I tried to use tableView.scrollToRow to scroll to the bottom of the tableView before I make the textField become the first responder but it's still not working. How would I do this?

```
                cell.textField.becomeFirstResponder()
```

Comment: can not understand that where's the plus button is

Comment: @UsamaAzam I just have a + button that appends to the array and creates a new row. When the row is created, if there are too many cells on the screen and the new row is created outside of view, the become first responder doesn't work since it's outside of view. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

`cell.textField.becomeFirstResponder()` will not have any effect if the cell which has `textField` is not visible at all, so you should rather try to bring the cell to visible area when user taps on "+" using

```
self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: row_of_cell_with_textField, section: 0), at: .middle, animated: true)
```

Comment: I did this but it's not working. It scrolls to the bottom but I THINK because it still hasn't finished scrolling by the time I'm setting the first responder, it still can't set it

Comment: in that case can you try using same with animated value as false? `self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: row_of_cell_with_textField, section: 0), at: .middle, animated: false)`

Comment: I tried that as well, didn't work sorry :( there has to be a solution but not sure why this doesn't work